# Node JS, mysql2 + pool connections, promise, universal function for mysql queries

Tags: node.js, promise, mysql2

I'm using: mysql2
I want to create universal QUERY function module, whic i will be used in any other modules.

My **app.js**:

```
//globals include
options          = require('./options'); //DB settings
db               = require('./lib/db'); //DB Driver
async function init(){
var  result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM log");
console.log(result);

}

init();
```

My **db.js**:

```
const { resolve } = require("bluebird");
const DataBase = require("mysql2"); // import the class

const pool = DataBase.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 50,
    host: options.db_host,
    user: options.db_login,
    database: options.db_name,
    password: options.db_password
}).promise();



module.exports.query = async function (sql) {
   const connection = await pool.getConnection();

   return connection.query(sql)
    .then(result =>{
      //console.log(result[0]);
      return result[0];
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
    .then(() => connection.release());
    

}
```

When i start **app.js**, i get:

```
 2022-12-23T01:20:49.362Z
 undefined
```

But if my use in db.js this code, i see, code is working fine (he shows ROWS in console log from DB):

```
module.exports.query = async function (sql) {
   const connection = await pool.getConnection();

   return connection.query(sql)
    .then(result =>{
      console.log(result[0]);
      //return result[0];
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    })
    .then(() => connection.release());
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the result of `connection.query` across all the chain of `.then()`'s.  Yes, promise chaining is better than callback-based API, but if you have promises go `async/await`.

This is a small sample code I created from your code.  It uses a MySQL DB of mine so the query is not for your table.

### Using Promise Chaining

#### db.js

```js
import config from './config.js';
import DataBase from 'mysql2';

const pool = DataBase.createPool(config.db).promise();

const query = async function (sql) {
    const conn = await pool.getConnection();
    return conn.query(sql)
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Query results: %o', result);
            return result;
        })
        .then((r) => {
            conn.release();
            return r;
        });
};

export default query;
```

#### index.js

```js
import query from "./db.js"

const result = await query('select * from Users');
console.log('Result: %o', result);
```

As you can see, you need to return from the first `then()` so the result is available in the second one.  Then, from the second one, you also return.

### Using Async/Await

#### db.js

```js
import config from './config.js';
import DataBase from 'mysql2';

const pool = DataBase.createPool(config.db).promise();

const query = async function (sql) {
    const conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const result = await conn.query(sql);
    conn.release();
    return result;
};

export default query;
```

Much simpler, right?

---

For completeness, my `config.js` is an implementation of [wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config).

---

### Update

Sorry, I forgot to tell you that I wrote this in **ES Modules**, not **CommonJS Modules** for an important reason:  I can use `await` anywhere I want.  I don't need the `init()` function.  Let's normalize writing server-side code in ES Modules. :-)